# Why is Windows 7 64 bit not recognising my IDE HDD in KVM?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to run Windows 7 64 bit on KVM on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-46-generic x86_64)`. If I install Windows 7 32 bit, the windows installer recognizes the IDE HDD, but the 64 bit version of the Windows 7  installer does not recognize any HDD. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

64-bit versions of Windows Vista and newer (this currently includes Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012) require the drivers to be digitally signed to load.

You can download Windows VirtIO Drivers from [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the ISO I was using was a custom image that broke some drivers.